# LGSVL Build in Unity Gives Pink Sky for Linux Target but not Windows

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine

I've built LGSVL in the appropriate version of Unity for both Windows and Linux and on both a Windows and Linux machine. Two shaders always seem to get nixed in the Linux build that are not nixed in the Windows build. I can fix one of them (Particles/Additive) by including it in the Graphics Settings "Always Include Shaders" list (which seems odd I should have to do), but the other, Skybox2CubeBlend refuses to work. My sky forever remains pink. I've thrown it (and the Day, Night, and RiseSet Cubemaps it uses) into a Resources folder as well with no greater results. It kinda seems like the shader is just not welcome within Linux but if I download and run a pre-compiled Linux version of the software, it works just fine. This would indicate that the shader itself must be okay and is just not making it into my build or something. Perhaps this is an LGSVL-specific build process issue. Any ideas? Again, it all works perfectly fine in Windows builds.

Comment: Please add this shader code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that within the LGSVL Project, in the Prefabs folder, there is an AssetBundleManager. This prefab has a special button in the Inspector Window to create the asset bundles for you dependent upon which target you are building for. Selecting the one for Linux x64 made it include all the necessary things within the asset bundle. No more pink sky!